# Java method not returning string

Tags: java, sparql

```
public static void searchLabel(String word) {
    String uri = null;
    String sparqlQueryString1 = sparqlQuerySetup + "SELECT * WHERE {?x uni:altLabel \"" + word + "\"^^xsd:string}";
    System.out.println(sparqlQueryString1);
    executeQuery(sparqlQueryString1);
    System.out.println(uri);

    getType(uri);
}

public static String executeQuery(String sparqlQuerystring1){
    String uri = null;
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQuerystring1);
    QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
    ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
    //ORGINEEL ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);       
    //ALS RDF ResultSetFormatter.outputAsRDF("", results);    
   // ResultSetFormatter.outputAsJSON(results);
    if (results.hasNext()) {
         uri = results.next().get("x").toString();
      }
    qexec.close() ;
    System.out.println(uri);
    return uri;
}
```

In the first method, I'm executing executeQuery. In the executeQuery I try to return "uri" and print it again in the searchLabel method, but it returns "null". It is being printed executeQuery method, just before returning uri.

I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that I have uri defined as null inside the searchLabel method. But if I remove it I can't execute the script (uri can't be resolved to a variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uri = executeQuery(sparqlQueryString1);
```

Comment: You might  have avoided the problem altogether if you'd just done the assignment with the declaration: `String uri = executeQuery(...);` In that case, you could even have made `uri` final.

Answer (score 1):

In the first method you...

1. Declare `uri` and initialize it with `null`.
2. Create a query string
3. print that out
4. execute the query via the 2nd method, which might or might not return a result that is not `null`
5. print out `uri`, which will be still null, because you never assigned any value to it
6. call `getType( null )`, because uri is still null

So, assuming that your 2nd method actually returns a result, you would have to assign that return value to the `uri` variable in the first method. Remember, the variable uri in the first method has nothing to do with the variable `uri` in the second method. They just happen to have the same name but they are not related nor the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign your return from `executeQuery` to your `uri` variable...

```
    String uri = null;
    String sparqlQueryString1 = sparqlQuerySetup + "SELECT * WHERE {?x uni:altLabel \"" + word + "\"^^xsd:string}";
    System.out.println(sparqlQueryString1);
    uri = executeQuery(sparqlQueryString1);
    System.out.println(uri);
```